# Desolate vs deserted

Tags: adjectives, word-difference

Is there a difference in meaning or usage between "desolate" and "deserted" (used to describe a place)?

Comment: A question like "What is the difference between _this_ and _that_?" can be markedly improved if you first look up the words in a few dictionaries, and then include some of the definitions you found in your question. That way, instead of starting from the beginning and telling you something you already know, we can better understand what you want to learn, and answer that more directly. You are welcome to do that here and we can reopen this question. See our [*Details, Please*... meta post](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) for more helpful tips.

Answer (score 8):

**Desolate** refers to a general emptiness.

> (of a place) uninhabited and giving an impression of bleak emptiness. [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/desolate)

**Deserted** implies that the place had people (or animals, etc.) occupying it at some point but has since been abandoned.

> (of a place) empty of people. [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/deserted)

Used in a sentence together:

> This city was once surrounded by farm fields, but a plague killed the crops. The people left the city and left it **deserted**. Now, with ruined silhouettes and a wasteland where nothing grows around it, the area looks **desolate**.

Answer (score 7):

It's a good idea to check English-language dictionaries when uncertain about the nuance between two words, as these might give more detail that doesn't show up in a translation dictionary:

> [**deserted**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/deserted) (adj) : (of a place) empty of people.
>
> [**desolate**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/desolate) (adj): 1.  (of a place) uninhabited and giving an impression of bleak emptiness.

"Deserted" is normally used as a neutral term.  A barren wasteland can be *deserted*, but so can a beautiful tropical beach.

"Desolate", on the other hand, always has negative connotations of both "without people" and "invoking feelings of hopelessness".  If an author describes a *desolate* landscape, it implies that there is little there to support life, and little reason for people to want to be there.